# get sum for multiple blocks

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table like this:

```
name | day | score
------------------
John |  1  |   4
John |  2  |   5
John |  3  |   6
Marc |  1  |   7
Marc |  2  |   4
Marc |  3  |   5
Paul |  1  |   8
Paul |  2  |   2
Paul |  3  |   3
```

I want to get the sum of the score for each person, but only for certain days, sorted by this sum. let's say I want to get the score-sum of the 1. and 2. day, this is what I expect:

```
name | sum(score)
-----------------
Marc |    11
Paul |    10
John |     9
```

this is what failed:

```
SELECT name, sum(score) FROM mytable WHERE day<=2
```

I think I have to surround the `sum(score)`-part with some `IF`-statement, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `group by`

```
SELECT name, sum(score) FROM mytable WHERE day<=2 group by name
```

Comment: oh, that was too easy. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum` function and `group by` clause for grouping the result.

**query**

```
select name,sum(score) as score
from myTable
where day in (1,2)
group by name
order by sum(score) desc;
```

[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4edc0/4)